# Rails: categories and sub-categories model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2, categories

Without using any gems how do I do this in rails?

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

I have a table that consists of | id | level1 | level2 |

Level 1 being the main category and Level 2 being the subcategory

I would like it displayed in the view like above.

After looking around on the internet everyone seems to recommend using acts-like-a-tree gem, but i want to avoid using them as I'm fairly new to rails and I would like to understand how to do things rather than turn to gems.

Your help is much apreciated

Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :catalogue
    has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category"
end
```

Controller:

```
class CataloguesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'main'
  def index
   @cats = Catalogue.all
  end

  def categories
   @cat = Catalogue.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

View:

```
<ul class="unstyled-list">

    <% @cat.categories.order([:level1]).each do |cat|%>
        <li><%=  cat.level1 %></li>
        <li><%= cat.level2 %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Create a model that has references to [itself](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) for a sub-category (or a sub-sub-category, etc):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "Category", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :parent_category, :class_name => "Category", :optional => true
end
```

- the `has_many` defines a `subcategories` association of the model type `Category`. Ie it uses the same table.
- the `belongs_to` defines a relation back to the parent category, accessible via `@category.parent_category`

For more information on model associations, `has_many` or `belongs_to`, read the [Associations Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

To create the table use this migration:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :category do |t|
      t.string      :text
      # table name should be in plural 
      t.references  :parent_category, foreign_key: { to_table: :categories }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

*Note*: this table format is (slightly) different than you proposed, but I suppose that this is not a real problem.

The [Migrations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) contains more information on database migrations.

In your controller use

```
def index
  @category = nil
  @categories = Category.find(:all, :conditions => {:parent_id => nil } )
end
```

to find all categories without a parent, ie the main categories

To find all sub-categories of any given category use:

```
# Show subcategory
def show
  # Find the category belonging to the given id
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  # Grab all sub-categories
  @categories = @category.parent_category
  # We want to reuse the index renderer:
  render :action => :index
end
```

To add a new category use:

```
def new
  @category = Category.new
  @category.parent_category = Category.find(params[:id]) unless params[:id].nil?
end
```

It creates a new category and sets the parent category, if it is provided (otherwise it becomes a Main Category)

Note: I used the old rails syntax (due to laziness), but for modern versions of Rails the principle is the same.

In your `categories/index.html.erb` you can use something like this:

```
<h1><%= @category.nil? ? 'Main categories' : category.text %></h1>
<table>
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to category.text, category_path(category) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) unless category.parent.nil? %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category_path(category), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete unless category.parent.nil? %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<p>
  <%= link_to 'Back', @category.parent_category.nil? ? categories_path : category_path(@category.parent_category) unless @category.nil? %>
  <%= link_to 'New (sub-category', new_category_path(@category) unless @category.nil? %>
</p>
```

It shows the name of the selected category (or Main Category) and all of its sub-categories (in a nice table). It links to all sub-categories, showing a similar layout, but for the sub-category. In the end it adds a 'new sub-category' link and a 'back' link.

Comment: Sorry im fairly new to this ive added what i have to the post can you help some more please?

Comment: in order to make `:parent_category` work, I needed to add `:foreign_key=>"parent_id"` . Otherwise, it was returning nil.

Comment: I am new to rails. Have followed this answer but can't find parent.subcateogries.
can someone help please.

Comment: In Rails 5, if you're creating a migration to add to an existing table called `categories`, you can use:

`add_reference :categories, :parent, foreign_key: {to_table: :categories}`

Comment: In Rails 5 you need  to add `optional: true` to the `belongs_to` relation.
`belongs_to :parent_category, class_name: "Category", optional: true`,
because whenever we define a `belongs_to` association, it is required to have the associated record present.

Comment: Strangely in Rails 5.1 you need a `belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'` instead of `:parent_categories` for it to work.

Comment: ^ Yup the last comment is correct! `parent_category` doesn't exist in the schema.

Comment: The `parent_category` is the accessor that will be created by the `belongs_to` statement. I updated the example and added a link to the 'self join' documentation. Hopefully this makes things a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :category do |t|
      t.string      :text
      t.references  :parent
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do categories and courses or posts

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy 
    belongs_to :user
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category

end
```

this is the method for getting all the categories and courses

```
def get_category_courses
         @category = Category.all.order(:name)
         @course =Category.joins(:courses).select('categories.id, courses.id as course_id, categories.name as category_name, courses.subject').
         group('categories.id, courses.id').paginate(page: params[:page],per_page:10)
         @courses= @course
          record_activity("#{@user} accessed category courses list  #{DateTime.now}")
          
         render json: {success: true, :category => @courses}
        end 
        end
```

this is the response from the query

```
{
    "success": true,
    "category": [
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 8,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "English"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 545,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "English"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 4357,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": null
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 5359,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "Cosmos"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 6303,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "English"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 6702,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "Algebra-X"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 14317,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "Cosmos"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 16699,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": null
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 25384,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": "Cosmos"
        },
        {
            "id": 586513,
            "course_id": 31644,
            "category_name": "Christianity",
            "subject": null
        }
    ]
}
```