# Ruby on Rails: Organize records from ActiveRecord based on its parent_id or parent record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this simple array delivered from activerecord

```
[#<Product id: 1, parent_id: , text: "Hurray">, #<Product id: 2, parent_id: 1, text: "Hurray again">, #<Product id: 3, parent_id: 1, text: "Hurray again 2">, #<Product id: 4, parent_id: 2, text: "Boo yeah !">]
```

As you can see each entry has a `parent_id`. Now the the idea here is to group the `Product` along with its child product. Now the way the child product is known by, is by its `parent_id`. So for example, `Product 2's` parent product is `Product 1`.

Now, I have setup the database and all the actions in the controller in such a way that the result delivered should be delivered as mentioned below.

Although, i am unable to do now is show the detail in a simple format. Which probably should look like on a rails erb page

```
1. Product 1 has products
2. Product 2 has products
   1. Product 4
3. Product 3 has products
   Nil
4. Product 4 has products 
   Nil
```

I tried my running a loop of all the product and put an if condition with something like `if n.parent_id.present?`. But I only got one level deep, as you can see *I am expecting the result is multiple levels and result is different all the time*.

Any help or guidance here is appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE: What I tried is this

```
<%@products.each do |n|%>
    <li><%=Product "#{n.id}" has products%></li>
        <%if n.parent_id.present?%>
        <li><%=Product "#{n.id}" has products%></li>
        <%end%>
<%end%>
```

The problem you see here, I cant go on using if/else if the level is too deep. In other words I am trying to display a thread based view for products.

Hope I am making sense :).

Comment: Please post the code you tried

Answer (score 2):

Please use acts_as_tree or the ancestry gem. This http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry should give you the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

I see a deep lack of understanding ActiveRecord Relations.

Using a foreign key inside your table is not for multiple ownings. You'd need to create a one to many association, probably.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: yes I do understand the association basics. That being said, please note, `parent` is not a model/table which makes `parent_id` a foreign_key. Its just a way to setup a simple way of threading based display. Although I know I could about associating it, but i was hoping to do without it

Comment: I guess I'm missing something, sorry. But, why would you try to do something with another method while you could do it with associations pretty straight forward?

Comment: Its because Product is already associated with 3 other models and in the long run the above solution i am looking for will be run for all the three models. Adding another model will just create problems I believe. As for the number of calls being made to the database is concerned, right now its 3, but if I go with another model, it could get somewhere around 9 simultaneous calls to the db (3*3)

Comment: Why wouldn't this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197897/categories-and-sub-categories-model-rails

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstood what you are asking (table organized as a tree), I had some thoughts about similar problem and discussed it with a friend. Notice that is a not-so-small issue anyway, there are various ways to face it. The one I prefer is this:

Create a new table and call it product_products. In this way you obtain one important point: you can have one product in multiple parents (which may happen) and you can "easily" build nested levels. Notice that you still need to put a depth limit (or otherwise you must block in some way loop referencing), to avoid loop references destroy your server.

For printing that out, to clean up your mind, I suggest you to use a *recursive method* (a helper in this case).

For example (based on your current table structure, not on the one I suggested):

```
def tree_print(products)
    products.each do |product|
        nested_tree_print(product)
    end
end

def nested_tree_print(product)
    print product.name
    nested_tree_print(product) unless product.parent_id.nil?
end
```

Please consider it pseudocode, is just a basic idea how to solve the problem.
You can also read about these two gems: [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) and [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree)

**Update 1**

After reading your comments, let's suppose that `Product has_many products`, here is some pseudocode:

```
def tree_print(products)
    products.each do |product|
        nested_tree_print(product)
    end
end

# Consider this like a private method, you should use the other in views
def nested_tree_print(product)
    product.products.each do |printable_product|
        print printable_product.name
        nested_tree_print(product) unless product.parent_id.nil?
    end
end
```

Care that this code is definitely not optimized. If there aren't a lot of products is ok (you will benefit a lot from caching everything in memory), it can cause stackoverflows easily and you need to check for max-depth.

Comment: Yes, you are right I could go about creating another table. Though I was hoping to do with this one table itself. As for recursive, could you give me a quick glance on to code it in helper? And yes, I was hoping on to stop/break the loop after 5 iterations

Comment: I was writing an example, depending on various things (product.has_many products or has_one?), my code should be changed, is just a basic suggestion on how you can write some recursion code. With two tables you can do more, but maybe you don't need one product with multiple parents, if that's the case you can keep working in the way you are doing.

Comment: thanks for pseudocode. I will add more to it and work on it accordingly. Thanks again !

Comment: No problem, I hope you'll find it helpful, let me know ;)

Comment: Sure. And I see that there is only one command print the name. In future I plan on having more than one fields in the database, like `text`, `description` and so on, that being said how do I go on adding more to it. i ask because there will be different stylings i will need to add too. Sorry I am new to programming and still trying to wrap my head around recursion.

Comment: I added another example, I don't think it's enough but this is not simple if you are a beginner.

Comment: hm, I understand. Well thanks. I will go work on it and see what can done. Thanks again :)