# Post and category relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, categories

I need to create a relationship where in blog posts belongs to many categories and categories has many posts and categories. How can i do it with gem or with self referential

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197897/categories-and-sub-categories-model-rails

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you should not look for a gem to do this, rails got everything you need to easily define your models.

I could go ahead and describe the process by Ryan Bates does it a lot more better that I would ever be able to.. have a look at his railscasts,
[#163 Self-Referential Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) in particular.